# Vector projection on matrix along diagonal

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there a easy way how to produce following matrix:

```
a = 
  4 5 6 7
  3 4 5 6
  2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4
```

which is a projection of vector [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] along diagonal?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the functions [HANKEL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hankel.html) and [FLIPUD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/flipud.html):

```
a = flipud(hankel(1:4,4:7));
```

Or using the functions [TOEPLITZ](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/toeplitz.html) and [FLIPLR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fliplr.html):

```
a = toeplitz(fliplr(1:4),4:7);
a = toeplitz(4:-1:1,4:7);       %# Without fliplr
```

You could also generalize these solutions to an arbitrary vector where you have chosen the center point at which to break the vector. For example:

```
>> vec = [6 3 45 1 1 2];  %# A sample vector
>> centerIndex = 3;
>> a = flipud(hankel(vec(1:centerIndex),vec(centerIndex:end)))

a =

    45     1     1     2
     3    45     1     1
     6     3    45     1
```

The above example places the first three elements of the vector running up the first column and the last four elements of the vector running along the first row.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this alternative solution:

```
a = bsxfun(@plus, (4:-1:1)', 0:3)
```

The corresponding general solution which accepts any vector and any column length:

```
x = randi(50, [1 10])
num = 5;
idx = bsxfun(@plus, (num:-1:1)', 0:(numel(x)-num));
a = x(idx)
```

with a sample output:

```
x =
    41    46     7    46    32     5    14    28    48    49

a =
    32     5    14    28    48    49
    46    32     5    14    28    48
     7    46    32     5    14    28
    46     7    46    32     5    14
    41    46     7    46    32     5
```